Need to seal old aluminum windows - take off this black plastic lining?
My windows are from the 1980s and they leak air real bad. On some of the windows, in the winter time I have blocks of ice on the bottom on the inside from so much condensation.
I can not afford to replace my windows. However, I read that you can glaze windows where you basically take caulking and put on the edge of the window. On my windows have this old plastic lining. Do I pull that off and put the caulking there instead?
Also, is there anything else I can do to make them have less condensation in the winter?




If I understand what you mean, that black "plastic" in your first pic is actually supposed to be rubber or vinyl weatherstripping/molding (it may be hardened to a more plastic consistency due to age and weather).

Correct, whatever it used to be it is hard and brittle now. Comes right off.

Do the muntins actually hold individual panes of glass, or is the window a single pane of glass with the muntins overlaid?
